# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error in R

Tags: r, loops, count

I have got a column with different numbers (from 1 to tt) and would like to use looping to perform a count on the occurrence of these numbers in R.

```
count = matrix(ncol=1,nrow=tt) #creating an empty matrix
for (j in 1:tt)
{count[j] = 0} #initiate count at 0



for (j in 1:tt) 
 {
  for (i in 1:N) #for each observation (1 to N)
    {
        if (column[i] == j) 
           {count[j] = count[j] + 1 }

     }
  }
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this error.

```
Error in if (column[i] == j) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So I tried:

```
for (i in 1:N) #from obs 1 to obs N
if (column[i] = 1) print("Test")
```

I basically got the same error.

Tried to do abit research on this kind of error and alot have to said about "debugging" which I'm not familiar with.

Hopefully someone can tell me what's happening here. Thanks!

Comment: What's `column`? you don't define it in your code in the question. Please also give the code you use to construct `column`.

Answer (score 2):

As you progress with your learning of R, one feature you should be aware of is *vectorisation*. Many operations that (in C say) would have to be done in a loop, can be don all at once in R. This is particularly true when you have a vector/matrix/array and a scalar, and want to perform an operation between them.

Say you want to add 2 to the vector `myvector`. The C/C++ way to do it in R would be to use a loop:

```
for ( i in 1:length(myvector) )
    myvector[i] = myvector[i] + 2
```

Since R has *vectorisation*, you can do the addition without a loop at all, that is, *add a scalar to a vector*:

```
myvector = myvector + 2
```

*Vectorisation* means the loop is done internally. This is much more efficient than writing the loop within R itself! (If you've ever done any Matlab or python/numpy it's much the same in this sense).

I know you're new to R so this is a bit confusing but just keep in mind that often loops can be eliminated in R.

With that in mind, let's look at your code:

The initialisation of `count` to 0 can be done at creation, so the first loop is unnecessary.

```
count = matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=tt)
```

Secondly, because of vectorisation, you can compare a vector to a scalar.
So for your inner loop in i, instead of looping through `column` and doing `if column[i]==j`, you can do `idx = (column==j)`. This returns a vector that is `TRUE` where `column[i]==j` and `FALSE` otherwise.

To find how many elements of `column` are equal to `j`, we just count how many `TRUE`s there are in `idx`. That is, we do `sum(idx)`.

So your double-loop can be rewritten like so:

```
for ( j in 1:tt ) {
    idx = (column == j)
    count[j] = sum(idx) # no need to add
}
```

Now it's even possible to remove the outer loop in `j` by using the function `sapply`:

```
sapply( 1:tt, function(j) sum(column==j) )
```

The above line of code means: "for each j in 1:tt, return function(j)", an returns a vector where the j'th element is the result of the function.

So in summary, you can reduce your *entire code* to:

```
count = sapply( 1:tt, function(j) sum(column==j) )
```

(Although this doesn't explain your error, which I suspect is to do with the construction or class of your `column`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not use for loops, but use the count function from the plyr package. This function does exactly what you want in one line of code.